# Add a delete button in a <li> that deletes it on click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put a DELETE button next to each new appended `<li>` element that should delete the item, but I can't figure out how.

```js
let addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var item = document.getElementById("item").value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(item);
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    li.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById('todo-list').appendChild(li);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="add-todo">
            <input type="text" id="item">
            <button type="submit" id="add-btn">ADD</button>
        </div>
        <div class="added-lists">
            <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `button` element and append it to the `li`. Add a click event listener on the button that calls a function, and inside the function delete the buttons' parent element.

```js
let addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");
addBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var item = document.getElementById("item").value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.textContent = "x";
  btn.style.marginLeft = "10px";
  li.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(btn);
  document.getElementById('todo-list').appendChild(li);
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentElement.remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="add-todo">
      <input type="text" id="item">
      <button type="submit" id="add-btn">ADD</button>
    </div>
    <div class="added-lists">
      <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="/script.js"></script>
</html>
```